# Access denied when there is "_trust" in URL

Tags: 2013, adfs

ADFS is used for authentication.

When user access the site using below URL then everything works fine

```
https://sitecollURL/
```

If user uses below URL then they receive access denied

```
https://sitecollurl/_trust
```

What can be possible cause for the same?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is an ADFS issue... You can't have a site beginning with an underscore and SP also treats folders beginning with an underscore as system folders.

See https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/905231/information-about-the-characters-that-you-cannot-use-in-site-names,-fo

Comment: I was thinking it as ADFS issue because while configuring ADFS, _trust virtual directory gets created automatically and we need to specify permission there, but I am not sure about it